# Load More option in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

**Android ListView]** *ListView should display first 10 result and then it should display an option like "LoadMore" when I click on 'LoadMore option ' then listview will display with 10 more result and again the "LoadMore" option should display..How to do.*

**XML**

```
<ListView
      android:id="@+id/subCategory"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="5"
      android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
      android:divider="#fff"
      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
      android:fadingEdge="none">
 </ListView>
```

**AdapterClass**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String>   mData   = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater      mInflater;

    public MobileListAdapter(Activity activity) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile_page, parent, false);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String str = mData.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(str);
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }

}
```

**ActivityClass**

```
public void setData() {
    mobileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem(str[i]);
        mobileList.add(str[i]);
    }
    Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
    btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");
    lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Starting a new async task
            //new loadMoreListView().execute();
        }
    });
```

Now what else i have to do in this to show the loadmore option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add FooterView for ListView as follows

```
lv.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Take **Button** as footerView and write **onClick**() for loading remaining items.

**UPDATE :**

You are storing data in ArrayList but you are not using anywhere, just write following in **onClick**()

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    mAdapter.addItem(str[i]);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: i have already that part the doubt is that i have data after 10 records i want to set 10 more records in the listview

Comment: @PoojaDubey If you load 10 more records then the button will automatically move to 21st position of ListView.

Comment: so i am confused what i have to do for this

Comment: should i call the same function setData() on each click

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this code...I have edited your code...based on your question..**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String>   mData;//   = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater      mInflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> data) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mData=data;
    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View row=convertView;

        if (row == null) {  
            row=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile_page, parent, false);
            holder=new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).toString());
        return row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            textView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.androidexam;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String str[]={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20",
            "21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29"};
    ListAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> mobileList;
    int index=0;
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.subCategory);

        setData();

    }
    public void setData() {

        mobileList = new ArrayList<String>();


        if(str.length<=10)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
               /* mAdapter.addItem(str[i]);*/
                mobileList.add(str[i]);
            }
        }else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
                   /* mAdapter.addItem(str[i]);*/
                    mobileList.add(str[i]);
                    index=i;
                }
        }


        mAdapter=new ListAdapter(this, mobileList);
        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
        btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);


        btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    for (int i = index+1; i < str.length; i++) {
                           /* mAdapter.addItem(str[i]);*/
                            mobileList.add(str[i]);

                            index=i;

                            if((i+1)%10==0)
                                break;
                        }

                     mAdapter=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, mobileList);
                     lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            }
        });
    }
}
```